# Import Azure Policy in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-policy

I have 100+ Azure polices which i want to import to Azure portal. I don't want to create each policy 1 by 1.  I am looking for some import options. These policies should be created and then applied at Management Group or Subscription level. MG / Subscription is already created.

Is there a way I can write Terraform code and create / apply these policies at MG / Subscription level already created ?

I am trying to import policies from here

```
https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-caf-enterprise-scale/tree/main/modules/archetypes/lib
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: If it were me, fastest way would be to use powershell to generate the `.tf` files.  Otherwise 
 as far as I know, terraform can't read ARM files.

Comment: Are the policy definitions `built-in` or `customized`? If `built-in` why import is needed?

Comment: Policies are Customized.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsondecode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsondecode) and [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/fileset) to prosess all Azure Policies.

```
locals {
  policies    = fileset(path.module, "path_to_policy_definitions/*.json")
  data        = [for item in local.policies : jsondecode(file("${item}"))]
}
```

The list of policies can be iterated over with `count  = length(local.data)`. Specify arguments as required by [azurerm_policy_definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_definition#name). For example name can be fetched with: `local.data[count.index].name`.

Use [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsonencode) to fetch the policy rule in correct format. `"${jsonencode(local.data[count.index].properties.policyRule)}"`